# html alignment for div's inside td

Tags: html

I need to align two fields **Amount** and **Pay by** horizontally also vertically(middle).**Creidt** and **Debit** should go down.How can i achieve this.Pls help

```
<table style="height: 82px;border:solid 1px blue;">
<tr><td class="style2">Amount:<div>Credit</div>
<div>Debit</div>
</td><td class="style1">800 Rs
<div>1000</div>
<div>200</div>
</td><td class="style3" style="font-weight:bold;">Pay by: </td><td>12/06/2010</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontal align:** http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

**Vertical align:** http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: i am aware of the alignment..but here i need Amount and Pay By to be aligned horizontally, vertically(middle),,and Debit and Credit should come down..

Comment: can you show what alignment you want, because I'm not sure I see output you try have?